# Angular js escaping "é" in href attribute

Tags: angularjs

[image]

Normally, this link redirects to #/wines/scope=rosé.

If I use angular, the link redirects to #/wines?scope=ros%C3%A9.

The source is not altered in any way by angular, only the behavior when clicking on it.

How can I make angularjs redirect to the link with the é instead of the %C3%A9?

Comment: What encoding is the page in? 0xC3 0xA9 is the UTF-8 encoding for 'é'... I have a feeling the behaviour you want depends on the browser too (how it displays non-ASCII text in the location bar).

Comment: You are right, I am using UTF-8. However, even with just UTF-8, I can use the href without any problems in my document. The replacing only happens once I activate angularjs.

Comment: Fascinating, +1. I have no idea why!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn off URL manipulation in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611214/turn-off-url-manipulation-in-angularjs)