# Turn off URL manipulation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, address-bar, location-provider, route-provider

I'm trying to write my first web-app with Angular.

In the normal mode (html5Mode off), Angular forces the address's hash part to look like a "path" (adding a leading "/"), and encodes special characters - for example, it allows a single "?" and "#" in the hash and replaces the others with %3F and %23.

Is there a way to turn this feature off? I don't want to use the *$locationProvider* / *$routeProvider* features - I want to parse the hash myself (In my case, the user's will enter some "free text" in the hash to search inside my website).

I read that the routeProvider cannot be configured to use regular expressions...

If htmlMode is turned on, then the address's hash part is not forced to look like a path (no leading "/"), but it still encodes special characters.

I'm aware that some browsers might encode/escape the special characters anyway, but if the user managed to enter some special characters in its address bar then I don't want to change it.

Thanks

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Not sure of the side effects of this, but it gets the job done.  Note that it will disable all location manipulation from the angular app, even if intended.

```
angular.module('sample', [])
    .config( ['$provide', function ($provide){
        $provide.decorator('$browser', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
            $delegate.onUrlChange = function () {};
            $delegate.url = function () { return ""};
            return $delegate;
        }]);
    }]);
```

ES6 variant:

```
angular.module('sample', [])
    .config(["$provide", $provide => {
        $provide.decorator("$browser", ["$delegate", $delegate => {
            $delegate.onUrlChange = () => { };
            $delegate.url = () => "";

            return $delegate;
        }]);
    }]);
```

Tested in Chrome 30, IE9, IE10.
Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/16678065/369724

Comment: Huh, I gave up this feature idea a long time ago... Just for the record, I'm accepting your answer even though I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully someone on the angularjs team will stumble across this and tell me that there is a right way.  This solution took much trial/error and wasn't found until I started reading angular's source code. Customer is now happy, and I'm going to scrap the framework as so soon as I have time.  It is an impressive toy, but has proven impractical to learn and extend.

Comment: Angular retries to manipulate the location which leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: This code fails when you use ng-include anywhere on the page. It simply stops working and throws plenty of errors.

Comment: This appears to be a good workaround for angularjs 1.4.3. ng-include works as well.

Comment: Worked perfect for me, when used angular with PJAX in same project!

Comment: Savior! It took ages to find this, but this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

I use a local copy of angular.js. Search for

```
$browser.onUrlChange(function(newUrl, newState) {
```

and

```
$rootScope.$watch(function $locationWatch() {
```

comment out the corresponding lines and angularjs will stop watch for location url changes.

Comment: thanks, would have been so easy to make an option for this in angularjs

Answer (score 2):

Thank @greg.kindel 's answer, you help me find a solution to solve anchor problem.
This code let AngularJS app IGNORE some hash pattern, keep it working like browser default. I don't need enable html5Mode, and ngRoute still working. :)

```js
app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$browser', ['$delegate', '$window', function ($delegate, $window) {
        // normal anchors
        let ignoredPattern = /^#[a-zA-Z0-9].*/;
        let originalOnUrlChange = $delegate.onUrlChange;
        $delegate.onUrlChange = function (...args) {
            if (ignoredPattern.test($window.location.hash)) return;
            originalOnUrlChange.apply($delegate, args);
        };
        let originalUrl = $delegate.url;
        $delegate.url = function (...args) {
            if (ignoredPattern.test($window.location.hash)) return $window.location.href;
            return originalUrl.apply($delegate, args);
        };
        return $delegate;
    }]);
}]);
```

Tested in Chrome 69, Firefox 62

AngularJS 1.7.4

Comment: Hi Dragon,

Can you please adjust this answer to use rest parameters? EsLint complains about the above code otherwise.

Comment: @Naomi Done. (prefer-rest-params)

Answer (score 2):

The workaround from @greg.kindel (the accepted solution) didn't work for me.  It threw lots of errors about an infinite digest loop.  I'm using Angular 1.5.8.

I was able to adjust that workaround to the following to get things working.  I hope it saves someone else grief.

```
angular.module('sample', [])
  .config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$browser', ['$delegate', '$window', function ($delegate, $window) {
      $delegate.onUrlChange = function () {};
      //
      // HACK to stop Angular routing from manipulating the URL
      //
      // The url() function seems to get used in two different modes.
      //
      // Mode 1 - Zero arguments
      // There are no arguments given, in which case it appears that the caller is expected the
      // browser's current URL (a string response).
      //
      // Mode 2 - Three arguments
      // It receives three arguments (url, some_boolean, null).  It seems the caller is expecting
      // the browser's URL to be updated to the given value.  The result of this function call is
      // expected to be the $delegate itself, which will subsequently get called with no arguments
      // to check the browser's URL.
      //
      // The Hack:
      // We save the URL so that we can lie to the caller that the URL has been updated to what was
      // requested, but in reality, we'll do nothing to alter the URL.
      //
      var savedUrl = null
      $delegate.url = function (url, ...args) {
        if (!!url) {
          savedUrl = url;
          return $delegate;
        } else {
          return !!savedUrl ? savedUrl : $window.location.href;
        }
      };
      return $delegate;
    }]);
  }])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, Angular's routing is not obligatory, but then you must take care of reloading controllers, views, etc.

Comment: It's not obligatory, but it is always on.  You'll see this if you have a page (foo.html#abc). If you reload, it becomes (foo.html#/abc).  The conflict I had was with the window.history API failing when going pushState(...);back();forward(); because angular was replacing the url so the forward history was lost --even though I wasn't using routing at all in the angularjs part of the page.

Comment: I would try custom Angular build, though I've never done this myself :) The devil is in the `src/ng/location.js`. Reference to this file should be removed from `angularFiles.js` so that Grunt will not package it. I suppose you should also remove reference to `$LocationProvider` from `src/AngularPublic.js` to avoid errors.