# history.pushState and Angular $digest infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some code that calls `history.pushState` outside of Angular's scope. And after such a call, I get this:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.
<stack trace>...
```

I searched in Angular's issues and found that this was an actual issue in Angular 1.2.x, but I'm using Angular 1.4, so I shouldn't be getting this.

How can I prevent Angular from tracking the location at all, as I don't use it as a router? (Or how can I prevent this error from happening?)

Comment: This may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611214/turn-off-url-manipulation-in-angularjs

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi That indeed helped :) Anyways, I'd still like to know why is Angular still failing at this.